# UITest : How to get the buttons in rightview of UITextfield in a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, xctest

I have a table with custom cells which has a UITextField. I have set the accessibilityIdentifier to the cell and to the textfield. For 1 particular cell, I have added a view (which contain 2 buttons with accessibilityIdentifier) to the right view of the textfield. For UITesting, I have to tap the buttons in the textfield. Since I needed to tap the button, I tried *application.buttons* which should atleast show all the buttons, but didn't get it. Then I tried *textfield.buttons* as I added the buttons to the right view of the textfield, but that also didn't work.

Now what i want is, How can i get the buttons from the right view of the UITextField?